# CORS problem with Passport.js implemented in Azure Function in Static Web App. Passport returns 401

Tags: azure-functions, passport.js, http-status-code-401, azure-static-web-app

I am working on a project which uses the Azure Static Web App offering. I have implemented a Passport.js authentication strategy powered by azure-function-express which receives a JWT in an Authentication header, validates the JWT, and returns user information.

My system works locally, but returns a 401 unauthorized in deployment.

When tested in deployment, Application Insights infers that a resource is blocked due to a CORS issue, but does not specify which resource. It appears that the function executes despite the CORS issue, but returns a 401 even though the test account info is correct.

Does anybody have experience with this issue or know how to identify which resource is being blocked by CORS?

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOkpI.png)

[Azure Live Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzrgG.png) -- Sorry these cannot be expanded fully for readability

**CORS messages expanded**

The request has an origin header: 'https://icy-plant-mysiteID.centralus.azurestaticapps.net'.

CORS policy execution failed.

Request origin https://icy-plant-mysiteID.centralus.azurestaticapps.net does not have permission to access the resource.

**GetUserFromJwt Azure Function**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const createHandler = require("azure-function-express").createHandler;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongooseHelper = require('../config/mongoose');


// Configure passport, express
require('../config/passport')(passport);
require('../config/express')(app, passport);

mongooseHelper.connectToMongoose("GetUserIdFromJwt");

app.get('/api/getUserIdFromJwt', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json(req.user)
});

// Binds the express app to an Azure Function handler
module.exports = createHandler(app);
```

**API Call** (Called from client upon retrieval of JWT)

```
export const getUserIdFromJwt = (jwt) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      url: '/api/getUserIdFromJwt',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { "Authorization": jwt }
    }).then((res) => {
      resolve(res.data)
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(console.log("An error occured getting the User from JWT: " + err));
    });
  })
}
```

**passport config**

```
// Configure Passport
const User = require('../models/UserModel');
const JwtStrat = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

const PUB_KEY = **MY KEY**;


const passportOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: PUB_KEY,
  algorithms: ['OurAlgorithm'],
  passReqToCallback: true
}

const strat = new JwtStrat(passportOptions, (req, payload, done) => {
  User.findOne({ _id: payload.sub })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // Send id as User. Do not send personal info here.
        req.user = {id: payload.sub, role: payload.role}; 
        return done(null, req.user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      done(err, null)
    });
});

module.exports = (passport) => {
  passport.use(strat);
}
```

**Express Config**

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');


module.exports = (app, passport) => {
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
}
```

Comment: Could you please call the function with jwt in Postman?

Comment: Calling the function from Postman returns 401 Unauthorized, with Unauthorized in the body

Comment: According to the situation, you do not provide the right token

Comment: Could you please provide the code how to get token?

Comment: According to my understanding, you store the user in the mongo DB. When you log in, you will find the user in Mongo DB. If the user exist, you will return token. THen you use the token to call azure function.

Comment: Hi Jim, this is what I am doing. The system does work locally, but fails in production. Here is where I call the function:
`// If there is no JWT redirect to login
      const jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
      if (!jwt) this.props.history.push('/');

      // Get user
      const user = await getUserIdFromJwt(jwt);`

You can see that the JWT is indeed sent to the azure function. I have verified that the JWT is being created and sent to localStorage in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the issue after contacting Microsoft Technical support.

The Static Web App service offered by Microsoft makes internal use of the Authorization header, thus the token being sent to the function through the Authorization header was being modified or overwritten. The issue was solved by sending the JWT using a different header.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

1. Create Azure function
2. [Configure CORS for Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#cors)
3. Code. I use Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API to save the user. You can access [here](https://github.com/JimXu199545/express-function-jwt) to read my function code

**passport config**

```
const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
const User = require("../Models/UserModel");

// passport & jwt config
const { Strategy: JWTStrategy, ExtractJwt: ExtractJWT } = passportJWT;

// define passport jwt strategy
const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt");
opts.secretOrKey =
  "QOOC3nUVl9yTZiH2F0VYjOJhwm2ZkyBjWK7Mzo4bH54cNBBUQmp262S0Tx1eBBTT";
opts.algorithms = ["HS256"];
const passportJWTStrategy = new JWTStrategy(opts, function (jwtPayload, done) {
  // retreive mail from jwt payload
  const email = jwtPayload.email;
  User.findOne({ email: email }, (error, user) => {
    if (error) {
      return done(error, false);
    } else {
      if (user) {
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        done(null, false);
      }
    }
  });
});

// config passport
module.exports = function (passport) {
  // token strategy
  passport.use(passportJWTStrategy);

  // return configured passport
  return passport;
};
```

**GetUserFromJwt Azure Function**

```
const passport = require("passport");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const createHandler = require("azure-function-express").createHandler;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// init and configure passport
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Configure passport
require("../config/passport")(passport);

require("../config/mongo")
  .connect()
  .catch((error) => {
    throw error;
  });

app.get(
  "/api/getUserIdFromJwt",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json(req.user);
  }
);

// Binds the express app to an Azure Function handler
module.exports = createHandler(app);
```

4 Create jwt token

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const  secretOrKey =
  "QOOC3nUVl9yTZiH2F0VYjOJhwm2ZkyBjWK7Mzo4bH54cNBBUQmp262S0Tx1eBBTT";
const  token = jwt.sign(<your playlaod>, secretOrKey , { algorithm: 'HS256' });
const jwt= `JWT ${token}`
```

5. Test in Postman

```
GET https://testjsfun.azurewebsites.net/api/getUserIdFromJwt

Authorization : JWT <token>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort Jim. I identified the issue as another problem. Please see my post below.

Comment: Could you explain how to use the HTTP function to secure other routes? The way Azure Function work is so confusing coming from regular app/server setups in node